# Arraylist of Arrays with Java Stream

Tags: java, python, arrays, arraylist, java-stream

i got a method which returns a ArrayList with Arrays, like this inside:

```
{1,2,3}, {4,5,6}, {7,8,9}....

public int[] simulatePlays(BitBoard board, int number){
    int[] count = {0,0,0};

    while (number > 0){
        BitBoard b = new BitBoard(board);
        count[playRandomly(b)+1] += 1;
        number--;
    }
    return count;
}

public ArrayList<int[]> evaluateMoves(BitBoard board, int number){
    ArrayList<Integer> moves = board.listMoves();
    ArrayList<int[]> values = new ArrayList<>();

    for(int move : moves){
        board.makeMove(move);
        values.add(simulatePlays(board, number));
        board.undoMove();
    }
    return values;
}
```

Now i need to multiple the value of array[3]

> i mean as shown aboth value 3,6,9 the third value of every array.

with something and then pick the index of the max value. I could do it with two for loops but i would rather use Streams.

The Python code which doese what i want is:

```
values = [r* board.turn for l,m,r in evaluate_moves(board)]
max_val = max(values)
max_idx = values.index(max_val)
```

Can somebody help me ?

Comment: `array[3]` will not compile and I think you should provide a code to work on.

Comment: Note, for what it's worth, that streams and anything to do with indexes don't get along.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to nature of java streams it is not possible to retrieve element index from source. For example, you could use `parallelStream()` instead of `stream` and due to source would be splitted by [Spliterator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Spliterator.html) it still should work perfect.

To get information about only max multiple of 3rd element with some value you could use logic like that:

```
List<int[]> moves = new ArrayList<>();
moves.add(new int[]{1, 2, 3});
moves.add(new int[]{4, 5, 6});
moves.add(new int[]{7, 8, 9});

int someValue = 1;
Integer maxValue = moves.stream().map(array -> array[2] * someValue).reduce(0, Integer::max);
System.out.println(maxValue);
```

**Update** If you want to also have index, it is more appropriate to use 2 loops.

```
int maxValue = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
int indexMaxValueArray = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < moves.size(); i++) {
    if (someValue * moves.get(i)[2] > maxValue) {
        maxValue = someValue * moves.get(i)[2];
        indexMaxValueArray = i;
    }
}
System.out.println("maxValue = " + maxValue);
System.out.println("index of array in list = " + indexMaxValueArray);
```

Comment: nice that works, now i got the correct value but how can i find the index of the value ?
return values.indexOf(maxValue);
doesnt find the correct object because its nested inside of array, or ?

Comment: Assuming that `someValue` is greater than zero, it’s pointless to multiple every value with it when all you want is the maximum multiplied with `someValue`. Just search the maximum first and multiply afterwards, e.g. `moves.stream().mapToInt(array -> array[2]).max().get() * someValue`…

Comment: @Holger I know. Left it to be more easy to understand

Answer (score 0):

when you want to use Stream you can do it like this.

```
ArrayList<Integer> values = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(new Integer[]{1,2,3}));
    int valueindex = values.indexOf(values.get(2));//to get the index
   // Integer v = values.get(2);
    Integer s = values.stream().reduce((a,b)-> b*2).get();//multiply lastvalue by 2
    System.out.println(s);
    System.out.println(valueindex);
```

but when you want to use the stream to find the maxValue you can use this and it works the same:

```
Integer maxvalue = values.stream().reduce(0,Integer::max);
```